# Multiple TimePickers Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use a time picker to set multiple times on one page but cannot figure out how to do so. So far i can set one time to one distinct textbox ie. `TextViewA` .

What i want to do is set the text of the `Textview` whos `onClick` event triggered the timepicker.

Example When i hit `Time1` it will call the `OnClick` and set Time1.Text to what ever time i've assigned and the same for `Time2`.

Time Picker Class :

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),(TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener)getActivity(),hour,minute, android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}
}
```

OnClick for calling Timepicker:

```
Time1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
        DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
        timePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"time picker");

        }
    });
```

TimePicker Methood:

```
@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

    TextView Time1=  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextViewA);
    Tim1.setText(  hourOfDay + ":" +minute);

}
```

Any Help would be apprciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a tag when you show Time Picker. And check in callback.

```
int which;

Time1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
        which = 0;        
        ...
        }
    });
```

and

```
Time1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
            which = 1;        
            ...
            }
        });
```

and check when you get callback.

```
@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    if(which == 0) {
      Time1.setText(  hourOfDay + ":" +minute); 
    }
    else if (which == 1) {
      Time2.setText(  hourOfDay + ":" +minute); 
    }
}
```

Comment: This would only allow you to do it in order though?  I want to set 21 times on the page in no particular order. Help Appreciated though

Comment: @AidanDoherty That is your logic now. That's why we are programmer.